# Alternative for "component: () => import()" in VueJS routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I downloaded a template online to better understand VueJS and also create a web app. However I have a problem with routing. There is a function in my router's index.js that imports a path. The import syntax seems to be buggy due to some webpack issues. I tried a lot of different things but couldn't fix the bug so I want to find a workaround for that `import` syntax

This is my code for router's index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueAnalytics from 'vue-analytics'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Meta from 'vue-meta'

// Routes
import paths from './paths'
// import views from './views'

function route (path, view, name) {
  return {
    name: name || view,
    path,
    component: () => import(
      `../views/${view}.vue`
    )
  }
}

Vue.use(Router)

// Create a new router
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: paths.map(path => route(path.path, path.view, path.name)).concat([
    { path: '*', redirect: '/home' }
  ]),
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition
    }
    if (to.hash) {
      return { selector: to.hash }
    }
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
})

Vue.use(Meta)

// Bootstrap Analytics
// Set in .env
// https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics
if (process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS) {
  Vue.use(VueAnalytics, {
    id: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS,
    router,
    autoTracking: {
      page: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'
    }
  })
}

export default router
```

When i try to build it, I get an error saying:

```
ERROR in ./src/router/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/djangoProjects/martin - Copy/martin/src/router/index.js: Unexpected token (15:21)
```

The syntax error is on line (15:21), in the `route` function on the `component: () => import(` line and exactly on `import`. Fixing this issue is a pain so I was wondering if there is a workaround for it without using the `import` syntax?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly you'll need a plugin for babel that can handle dynamic imports.

Check out:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import

1. Run `npm install @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`
2. Create or open .babelrc

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```